# How to loop through query result set and execute specific code block depending on column recordcount

Tags: delphi

Once TADOQuery.Open (cte query) I would like to iterate over the result set and depending on whether there is only one record with check_id(50001, 50003) to execute one block of code.
In case when there are two or more records with the same check_id(50002) to execute different block of code.

Result set structure example.

| row_num | buyer_id | amount | check_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | 25 | 50001 |
| 1 | 10001 | 30 | 50002 |
| 2 | 10002 | 10 | 50002 |
| 1 | 10003 | 10 | 50003 |

Much appreciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Have you considered grouping the records on `check_id`, and then loop through the groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Group By` and `Count` in the SQL query to get a result like below.

### SQL:

```
SELECT check_id, COUNT(check_id) as check_id_count
FROM my_table
GROUP BY check_id
ORDER BY check_id;
```

### Result:

| check_id | check_id_count |
| --- | --- |
| 50001 | 1 |
| 50002 | 2 |
| 50003 | 1 |

Now you can iterate the records like that:

### Delphi code

```
cte.SQL.Text := 'SELECT check_id, COUNT(check_id) as check_id_count FROM my_table GROUP BY check_id ORDER BY check_id';
cte.Open;

while not cte.Eof do
begin
  case cte.Fields[1].AsInteger of
    1: Foo(cte.Fields[0].AsInteger)
    2: Bar(cte.Fields[0].AsInteger)
    // add more when necessary
  else
    FooBar; // every other count of check_id
  end;
  cte.Next;
end;
```